# String vector's sort compare and delete

Tags: c++, sorting, vector, compare

In C++ I have

```
vector < vector <string> > Kblist;
```

Inside `Kblist`, there are many clause, and numbers of `clauses=kblist.size();` and every clause in side `Kblist` is a string-type vector, and every word in sentence is split inside `Kblist[i]`.

What is the fastest way to find the sentence in same words like one in `"I love you"` and the other in `"you love i"` and delete these two sentence from `Kblist`, My code might be work run, but I think it is too slow because of to many circulate. So I wonder is there any better solution which is fast like using sort, `clause1==clause2` or other approach.

```
          for (int a=0; a<KBlist.size(); a++){
                for (int b=a+1; b<KBlist.size(); b++){
                    int checksize=0;
                    if (KBlist[a].size()==KBlist[b].size()) {
                        for (int c=0; c<KBlist[a].size(); c++){ 
                            for (int d=0; d<KBlist[b].size(); d++){
                                if (KBlist[a][b]==KBlist[c][d]&&KBlist[a][b+1]==KBlist[c][d]) {
                                    checksize=checksize+1; 
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                       if (checksize==c.size()) {
                                        inset=1;
                                        break;
                                    }
                    }
                }
            }
        }while (duplicate==0);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could iterate over each `std::vector` and use the algorithms of the standard-library.
There is [`std::find`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find/)

```
// find example
#include <iostream>     // std::cout
#include <algorithm>    // std::find
#include <vector>       // std::vector

int main () {
  int myints[] = { 10, 20, 30 ,40 };
  int * p;

  // pointer to array element:
  p = std::find (myints,myints+4,30);
  ++p;
  std::cout << "The element following 30 is " << *p << '\n';

  std::vector<int> myvector (myints,myints+4);
  std::vector<int>::iterator it;

  // iterator to vector element:
  it = find (myvector.begin(), myvector.end(), 30);
  ++it;
  std::cout << "The element following 30 is " << *it << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

there is [`std::find_if`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find_if/)

```
// find_if example
#include <iostream>     // std::cout
#include <algorithm>    // std::find_if
#include <vector>       // std::vector

bool IsOdd (int i) {
  return ((i%2)==1);
}

int main () {
  std::vector<int> myvector;

  myvector.push_back(10);
  myvector.push_back(25);
  myvector.push_back(40);
  myvector.push_back(55);

  std::vector<int>::iterator it = std::find_if (myvector.begin(), myvector.end(), IsOdd);
  std::cout << "The first odd value is " << *it << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

As you are working with `std::string` this shouldn't be a large problem.

Answer (score 0):

In your scenario it is probably better to use `std::multiset< vector <string> >` with comparator that compares `std::vector<string>` in a way you need it to. This will give you sorted container with duplicated values next to each other and cheap insert/erase.